# Compare time and date is included?

Tags: javascript, date

I have some Array with some data like this:

```
0: {start: "01:01", end: "16:53", day: "Saturday"}
1: {start: "03:02", end: "14:51", day: "Wednesday"}
```

I need to compare that data with the current date and time. *For example*, if today is Sunday I check it with

`const isToday = array && array.includes(toDay)`

But I need to show that the next day is Wednesday and if time is not between start and end then show `true` or `false`.

```
const isTime = () => {

  const time = moment().format(' h:mm:ss a');

  return staffTimeShift.map((i) => {
      if (i.start < time < i.end) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
  });

}
```

Comment: Any code you have achieved? Or some false code? Or any error message during your implementation?

Comment: @keikai I added code

Answer (score -1):

Edited version;

```
var list = [
    {start: "11:01", end: "21:53", day: "Sunday"},
    {start: "12:01", end: "22:53", day: "Monday"},
    {start: "13:01", end: "23:53", day: "Tuesday"},
    {start: "14:01", end: "22:53", day: "Wednesday"},
    {start: "15:01", end: "21:53", day: "Thursday"},
    {start: "16:01", end: "20:53", day: "Friday"},
    {start: "17:01", end: "19:53", day: "Saturday"},
    {start: "18:02", end: "18:51", day: "Sunday"}
];

var isTime = (obj,time,day) => {
   return (obj.start < time && time < obj.end && obj.day==day);
}

var findInList = (time,day)=>{
     var f;
     list.forEach((a)=>{
           if(f==null && isTime(a,time,day)) f=a;
     });
     return f;
};
```

try to send objects as parameter into the function;

```
findInList("15:00","Friday"); // undefined
findInList("15:00","Tuesday"); // {start: "13:01", end: "23:53", day: "Tuesday"}
```

Comment: Thanks to your code,  how about dates? I need to show the nearest date

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: anyone can help me?